# How to teach Visual Assist to assist me with smart pointers?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-assist

We usually define classes that are often used like this:

```
class SomeClass
{
    // Some code here
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<SomeClass> SomeClassPtr;
```

Because frankly having to type `std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>` every time is a suicide.

However Visual Assist, addon that my company **paid for** on top of Visual Studio, cannot cope with either `SomeClassPtr` or `std::shared_ptr<SomeClass>` and give member suggestions. Strangely though, I noticed that it handles `QPointer<SomeClass>` without any problems and gives `SomeClass` member suggestions as expected.

I noticed that status bar shows these two messages after I type `pointer->` (right after typing `>` character):

> IntelliSense: 'No additional information available' (See 'Troubleshooting IntelliSense in C++ projects' for further help.)

Which is weird because IntelliSense (I prefer to call it DumbSense) is turned off. Second message that appears only for 200ms:

> VA X: Parsing D:\ ... \myFile.cpp

`myFile.cpp` here refers to the file being currently edited.

Can I do anything at all to teach Visual Assist to properly give suggestions on `std::shared_ptr` smart pointers?

Comment: Interesting. This works for me without any issue for std::shared_ptr<> or std:unique_ptr<>. Although I am stuck on a 2013 version.

Comment: @drescherjm I just asked colleagues, it works for them too. But it has **never** worked for me. It's not just a random glitch, I simply have something wrong. I don't even know what information could I provide to help resolve this...

Comment: My only idea is: Have you tried rebuilding the symbol database?

Comment: @drescherjm I did now, no change.

Comment: Have you tried their user support forum? Perhaps if this is identified as a bug wholetomato will fix it soon.

Comment: I generally do not disable IntelliSense even though I have Visual Assist on all of my development machines.

Comment: @drescherjm It [is a bug](http://forum.wholetomato.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=10065), but it only happens to me (and the guy who reported it) and not to my colleagues. Also, when I tried to update visual assist the page has bug bold **Requires renewal of software maintenance** so I don't think I can update without help of the management and the sysadmin.